# route internet traffic through vpn failed (mikrotik, tried ikev2 & gre tunnel)

Tags: vpn, route, mikrotik

want to route some internet traffic through vpn, from local site to remote site router(R2)

```
R1: LOCAL site (750Gr3): LAN / 172.16.1.1/24, gre over ipsec tunnel ip: 192.168.8.1/24
R2: Remote site (CHR, cloud vm):  WAN / 172.18.0.4/24,LAN / 172.18.1.4/24, gre over ipsec tunnel ip: 192.168.8.2/24
```

use 8.8.8.8 for example, have add route on R1:
add distance=1 dst-address=8.8.8.8/32 gateway=192.168.89.2
(also tried use mangle to mark routing and use for routing)

(from R1 LAN side) mtr 8.8.8.8 can reach 192.168.8.2, but all ends there.

have tried nat traffic from 172.16.1.0/24 (and src-nat/src-nat), not work. (R2 can reach 172.16.1.x)
logging will only show first packet, then no further packet is pass through the policy.

and have tried different vpn setup:  a) ikev2 site to site vpn, with tunnel mode b) gre over previous ikev2 vpn. internet routing both not work (only LAN to LAN work).

Any ideas?